# Typescript Can't bind to parse errors

Tags: angular, typescript

I am not sure why I am getting this error message about not able to bind the model. I have an Input that is a type of Pagebreakable. Is there anything else I need to do for this to work?

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
> Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("

```
<div class="pagebreak" [ERROR ->][model]="evaluatePagebreak()" (change)="onPagebreakChange($event)"></div>"): TemplateEditorComponent@9:23 ; Zone: <root> ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Template parse errors:
Can't bind to 'model' since it isn't a known property of 'div'. ("
<div class="clear-comments"></div>
```

view

```
<div class="pagebreak" [model]="evaluatePagebreak()" (change)="onPagebreakChange($event)"></div>
```

Component

```
@Component({
    selector: ".pagebreak",
    template:
    `           
      <hr class='narrow' *ngIf="model.HasPagebreak" />         
      <span *ngIf="model.HasPagebreak" class='narrow'><a class='glyphicon glyphicon-remove' (click)='remove()'></a></span>
      <div *ngIf="!model.HasPagebreak" class='placeholder' (click)='add()'>put placeholder here</div>
      <hr class='wide' [class.enabled]="model.HasPagebreak"/>         
    `    
})
export class PageBreakComponent implements AfterViewInit, AfterViewChecked {

    @Input() model: Pagebreakable;
    @Output() change = new EventEmitter();    

    constructor(@Inject(ElementRef) private elementRef: ElementRef) {
    }

    add() {
        this.model.HasPagebreak = true;
        this.onChange();        
    }

    remove() {
        this.model.HasPagebreak = false;
        this.onChange();
    }

    onChange() {
        this.change.next({ value: this.model.HasPagebreak });
    }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        var offset = $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).offset().left;
        $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).css('margin-left', '-' + offset + 'px');        
        $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).css({ 'width': 'calc(100% + ' + offset + 'px)' });       
    }

    ngAfterViewChecked() {
        if (this.isActive()) {
            if (!$(this.elementRef.nativeElement).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).addClass('active');
            }
        } else {
            if ($(this.elementRef.nativeElement).hasClass('active')) {
                $(this.elementRef.nativeElement).addClass('active');
            }
        }
    }

    isActive(): boolean {
        return (<any>window).pagebreakMode === true;
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no such thing as model in angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The component you are referencing the pagebreak component from belongs to a Module. The pagebreak component also belongs to a Module.
Make sure both are in the "declarations" list of their respective Modules.
If they are in different modules, ensure that the pagebreak component is also listed in the "exports" list of its module, and that pagebreak's module is in the "imports" of the referencing component's module.

Comment: I believe the pagebreak component is in the correct Module because when I try to add it to another Module I get an error.  Uncaught (in promise): Error: Type PageBreakComponent is part of the declarations of 2 modules: RegimenModule and TemplateEditorModule!

Comment: Have you verified the other considerations? Is the component declared and exported from a module, and is that module imported in the module where the error is received?